# Invalid PostCSS Plugin found: [0]

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, yarnpkg, postcss, postcss-loader

I'm struggling now for days getting my Spring Boot App to work again...

I wanted to deploy my application to Heroku and I got a really strange error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found: [0]
at C:\Entwicklung\git\Coinlender\node_modules\postcss-load-plugins\lib\plugins.js:32:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at plugins (C:\Entwicklung\git\Coinlender\node_modules\postcss-load-plugins\lib\plugins.js:21:15)
at C:\Entwicklung\git\Coinlender\node_modules\postcss-load-config\index.js:64:18
at C:\Entwicklung\git\Coinlender\node_modules\postcss-load-plugins\lib\plugins.js:32:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at plugins (C:\Entwicklung\git\Coinlender\node_modules\postcss-load-plugins\lib\plugins.js:21:15)
at C:\Entwicklung\git\Coinlender\node_modules\postcss-load-config\index.js:64:18
at Object.module.exports.createDebug.debug.createDebug.default (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:94862:7)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:21:30)
at Object.module.exports (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:112728:15)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:21:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:94506:84)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:21:30)
at Object.24 (http://localhost:8080/app/main.bundle.js:13268:42)
at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/app/manifest.bundle.js:694:30)
at fn (http://localhost:8080/app/manifest.bundle.js:115:20)
at Object../src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts (http://localhost:8080/app/main.bundle.js:3641:1)
```

I googled and found out that my bindings are possibly not correct. So I executed

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

in order to set them correctly. But that did not help. Since then I'm getting this error.

I also found hints that it has something to do with my **postcss.config.js**, which was empty (it worked like that for 6 weeks now). So I added some plugins. It looks like this now:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: require('postcss-scss'),
  plugins: [
        require('postcss-sassy-mixins'),
        require('precss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
}
```

Also that didn't help. it still shows me the error that there's that invalid postcss plugin. (All those plugins in the postcss.conig.js are installed via npm).

Please see my **package.json** here:

```
{
  "name": "coinlender",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for coinlender",
  "private": true,
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.2.6",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.8.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "1.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "sockjs-client": "1.1.4",
    "webstomp-client": "1.0.6",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "7.0.22",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
    "browser-sync": "2.18.12",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.3",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "event-stream": "3.3.4",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "generator-jhipster": "4.5.6",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "lazypipe": "1.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "map-stream": "0.0.7",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.6",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.14",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.3",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.3",
    "webpack": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "3.4.2",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17",
    "sass-loader": "5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.0",
    "yargs": "6.6.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint 'src/main/webapp/app/**/*.ts'",
    "lint:fix": "tslint 'src/main/webapp/app/**/*.ts' --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
    "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
    "webpack:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060",
    "webpack:build:vendor": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build:dev": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:vendor && yarn run webpack:build:dev",
    "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js --progress --profile && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:test": "yarn run test",
    "test": "yarn run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js --watch",
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js"
  }
}
```

I'm searching and trying for 3 days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please could you share your package.json?

Comment: Sure. Please see my package.json in my post.

Comment: Have you seen this yet? It suggests updating your postcss-loader version to 1.3.3 https://github.com/davidtheclark/cosmiconfig/issues/77#issuecomment-317655599

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved this issue now. Unfortunately I'm not 100% what the issue was but I'm suspecting that the bindings from node-sass were somehow corrupted. So what I did is: I deleted the node_modules folder, made an yarn install and then a yarn run webpack:build (the new build was very important. It didnt work without that).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So now I got this error again, and wanted to confirm that the answer of Dan Cancro did the trick!

Here's exactly what I did (for others in order not to waste as much time as I did):

1. I changed "postcss-loader": "1.3.**0**" to "postcss-loader": "1.3.**3**"
2. Deleted **/node_modules** folder
3. removed **package-lock.json** file
4. ran **npm install**
5. ran **yarn run webpack:build**

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Ah hell. Amazing!